# "Read-only file system" when I try to touch in Mac OS Catalina

Tags: macos, unix, macos-catalina

I'm logged in as admin in MacOS Catalina. When I try to add quota file, I get this output:

```
sudo touch /.quota.ops.user
> touch: /.quota.ops.user: Read-only file system
```

Than I tried:

```
mount -uw /
```

...and got an error:

```
mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: Operation not permitted
mount: / failed with 77
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but you might be able to get the intended effect under Catalina with `touch /System/Volumes/Data/.quota.ops.user` -- this should enable quotas on the volume where user data is stored.

Comment: Thank you, this is also a good approach. The last link in Tetsujin's answer solves the problem.

Comment: Does the `.quota.ops.user` file even apply to the new APFS filesystem? I thought quotas worked rather differently there than in HFS+.

Comment: Note that `mount -uw /` works if you first boot into Recovery Mode by holding Command + r while booting, and then run `csrutil disable` in Utilities -> Terminal.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59395264/2919326 for more info.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Copied directly from Apple KB - [About the read-only system volume in macOS Catalina](https://support.apple.com/HT210650)*

TL:DR
With macOS Catalina, you can no longer store files or data in the read-only system volume, nor can you write to the "root" directory ( / ) from the command line, such as with Terminal.

> **macOS Catalina runs in a read-only system volume, separate from other files on your Mac. When you upgrade to Catalina, a second volume
>   is created, and some files may move to a Relocated Items folder.**
>
> macOS Catalina runs on a dedicated, read-only system volume called
>   Macintosh HD. This volume is completely separate from all other data
>   to help prevent the accidental overwriting of critical operating
>   system files. Your files and data are stored in another volume named
>   Macintosh HD - Data. In the Finder, both volumes appear as Macintosh
>   HD.
>
> [image]
>
> <sup>The Disk Utility app in macOS Catalina shows that Macintosh HD is
>   the read-only system volume and Macintosh HD - Data contains the the
>   rest of your files and data.</sup>
>
> If you upgrade to macOS Catalina from an earlier version of macOS, the
>   read-only volume is created during the upgrade process. Files or data
>   that you previously stored in the startup volume are now stored in
>   this new volume, and some of these files may appear in a new folder
>   called Relocated Items. You can check this folder for any files that
>   you can’t locate.
>
> With macOS Catalina, you can no longer store files or data in the
>   read-only system volume, nor can you write to the "root" directory ( /
>   ) from the command line, such as with Terminal.
>
> **About the Relocated Items folder**
>
> While creating the two separate volumes during the upgrade process,
>   files and data that couldn’t be moved to their new location are placed
>   in a Relocated Items folder. The Relocated Items folder is in the
>   Shared folder within the User folder (/Users/Shared/Relocated Items)
>   and available though a shortcut on the Desktop. The Relocated Items
>   folder includes a PDF document with more details about these files.

*Copied from en-gb site, link will redirect your your local language site

See also Ask Different - [Where does the upgrade to macOS Catalina move root “/” directory files?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371852/where-does-the-upgrade-to-macos-catalina-move-root-directory-files)

Comment: Thank you. How weird :/

Comment: Not so weird. It's a security feature that only about a 1 in thousands will ever notice. Most people don't even know what the Terminal application is, far less how to use it. Only a brave few ;-) who like to venture deeper into the system will ever notice

Comment: okay, I have a folder called U under /, which is probably created by some malware, how do I remove it now?

Comment: same situation @AeroWindwalker for a remote user. first off, i'll have to see if trying to remove via gui works.  and either way i'llproably have to clone, wipe, reformat, reinstall, clone.  during some apfs fiasco, about 100 random files (mostly applications) got copied to /

Comment: @AeroWindwalker & neuralstatic - raise this as a separate question, or search existing questions. No-one but the original poster of this answer [me] will ever see this buried down here.

Comment: @SteveChambers much more people than that will notice... every programmer needs access to change the files in the root (e.g. installing mongodb). That sucks!! thank you apple for restricting accesses, piece of s*it, it makes me love even more Linux!!!

Comment: As I mentioned earlier for similar reasons… ranting way down the comments here won't get you anywhere. Only me & Steve will ever be notified this comment even exists. No-one needs to install in `root` on Mac & never has. Mac does not handle `root` like unix.

Comment: any user who wants to delete Stocks, Memos, News or Chess will also notice (i.e me)

Comment: @JamesCat I’ve never understood why people feel the need to save a few MB of data by removing apps that will just be put back next update.

Comment: yeah I know, its just I want this Mac to be a DAW and just seems kind of seems silly that I have to have stocks and chess, don't see why it isn't possible to give you options in the installer to pick like most linux installs do

Comment: @JamesCat - it's not linux, it's a consumer OS.

Comment: that's a poor reason imo. its bad UX

Comment: @JamesCat - get used to it. It's locked down even tighter in Big Sur & Monterey. The boot drive is not only read-only, but also cryptographically signed & hashed. If the hash doesn't match it won't boot & your only option is to reinstall the OS.

Answer (score 4):

See complete answer with more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59395264/2919326

The command `mount -uw /` works if you first boot into Recovery Mode by holding Command + r while booting, and then run `csrutil disable` in Utilities -> Terminal.

Comment: FYI: this doesn't work on Big Sur/11.4  

Comment: It's "sudo mount -uw /"
and only works up to catalina. not in big sur or later.